# Faster way of creating new df with for loop and append

Tags: python, performance, dataframe, for-loop, append

I have an issue with a speed of compilation my code. I figure out how to solve, but this solution is pretty slow. Therefore I would like to ask you if you have an idea how to make it more clever/faster?

I have original df (about 100k lines) and I want to multiple each line 4x (make copy of that line) and jsut change one column - stats1 (for axample add 1) - Stats1 is allways 5 in origin df.

DF:

```
      Stats 1  Stats 2  Stats 3  Stats 4  Stats 5
Row 1       5        5        8        7        3
Row 2       5        8        3        7        9
Row 3       5        5        1        2        6

Output:
      Stats 1  Stats 2  Stats 3  Stats 4  Stats 5
Row 1       5        5        8        7        3
Row 1       6        5        8        7        3
Row 1       7        5        8        7        3
Row 1       8        5        8        7        3
Row 2       5        8        3        7        9
Row 2       6        8        3        7        9
Row 2       7        8        3        7        9
Row 2       8        8        3        7        9
Row 3       5        5        1        2        6
Row 3       6        5        1        2        6
Row 3       7        5        1        2        6
Row 3       8        5        1        2        6
```

This code works, but its really slow.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(df)):
    new = pd.DataFrame()
    new = new.append([df.loc[[i]]]*4,ignore_index=True)
    step = 0
    for j in range(0,4):
        new.loc[:,"Stats1"].iloc[j] = 5+step
        step += 1
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df,new])
new_df.reset_index(inplace = True, drop = True)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Stats 1': [5, 5, 5],
                        'Stats 2': [5, 8, 5],
                        'Stats 3': [8, 3, 1],
                        'Stats 4': [7, 7, 2],
                        'Stats 5': [3, 9, 6]},
                  index=pd.Index(data=['Row 1', 'Row 2', 'Row 3']))
```

This code should do just that faster:

```
df_new = pd.concat([df] * 4).sort_index()

generator = (i for i in range(0, 4))
col = pd.Series(generator)

df_new.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
df_new['Stats 1'] = df_new['Stats 1'] + pd.concat([col] * int(len(df_new) / 4)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The result:

```
      Stats 1  Stats 2  Stats 3  Stats 4  Stats 5
    0       5        5        8        7        3
    1       6        5        8        7        3
    2       7        5        8        7        3
    3       8        5        8        7        3
    4       5        8        3        7        9
    5       6        8        3        7        9
    6       7        8        3        7        9
    7       8        8        3        7        9
    8       5        5        1        2        6
    9       6        5        1        2        6
    10      7        5        1        2        6
    11      8        5        1        2        6
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If the output row order doesn't matter you could try as below. Had to remove the space in the column names in order to have it work with keyword arguments in `assign`.

```
df.columns = [name.replace(' ', '') for name in df.columns]
new_df = pd.concat([df.assign(Stats1=lambda x: x.Stats1 + i) for i in range(4)])
```

Basically we concatenate the same dataframe 4 times, but in each increment we increase the `Stats1` column by the increment. You'll have to compare the performance on your original dataset.